# CoreData fetch request - fetching all objects which have relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have 3 entities:

```
Topic <--->> subTopic <--->> Certificate.
```

What I want is a list of all topics, where a certificate exists (with no duplicates). Based on my initial reading (mainly this question: [CoreData performance: predicate on more to-many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896151/coredata-performance-predicate-on-more-to-many-relationships)) I worked out that the most efficient way (assuming it's possible) is to start at the certificate level, and derive the list of topics the list of certificates.

But that's as far as I got. How do I specify that while I want a list of topics back, the list I want will be based on all certificates? Is it possible to specify a predicate for the fetchrequest that can return a list of topics.

Is there a way of doing this without just manually following each certificate's relationships and just adding the topics found to an `NSSet` or something?

Thanks for any pointers (or equally - advise telling me to stop being silly, and here's the way I should be doing it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this at the moment, but a fetch request on the Topic entity with this predicate should work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(subtopics, $s, ANY $s.certificates != NULL).@count > 0"]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't allow me to pass it as the predicate for a fetchrequest. I get an error (which seems to be known: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762539/keypath-error-with-core-data-subquery-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller) `Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle $s.certificates.@count'`

Comment: @Matt: I have updated the predicate and it does not crash anymore and seems to fetch the right objects. - If you want to use this in a fetched results controller then you should keep in mind that a FRC tracks only changes to the fetched entity Topic itself, so adding or removing a Subtopic will trigger an update notification, but adding or removing a Certificate will not. Would that be a problem in your case?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out when I get a minute. It would be updates to the certificates that were most interesting, but they're unlikely to happen while the tableView is being displayed so I guess it wouldn't be a major problem!

Comment: I've marked this as accepted, because it does indeed do what is necessary! Like you said, adding a certificate doesn't trigger an update, which isn't a huge problem because of the way the updates happen, the fetchedRequestController really isn't actually doing that much! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Get all of the categories, however you want, no predicate required as you want all of them. Then get the topics like this (assuming sensible relationship names):

```
NSArray *topics = [[categories valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.subtopic"] valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjectstopic"];
```

Comment: this works perfectly - thanks! Is there anyway I can do this as an NSPredicate so I can feed it to a fetchedResultsController? Obviously I can do it manually using the array, but then I lose the benefits of the update notifications etc.